# IF block and variables - final ELSE always runs, never the first part

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a batch script that will check if FireFox is open, then depending, copy the profile to another folder (basically a backup).

The script below works if FF is closed, but not open.  If it's open when I run it, I always get the `ELSE ()` reply at the end and can't figure out why. I'm pretty new to batch files, but have searched around and can't see why it's not working.  My hunch is the `errorlevel`, therefore `value` isn't getting set properly...

```
set source = "C:\users\someUser\someFolder\FireFox\Profiles\wszashe.default"
set destination = "C:\users\someUser\someOtherFolder\"
@echo off

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "firefox.exe">NUL
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    echo wscript.quit MsgBox("Want to close FireFox?", 4, "Please choose."^) > yesno.vbs
    wscript //nologo yesno.vbs
    set value = %ERRORLEVEL%
    del yesno.vbs
) ELSE (
    robocopy %source% %destination% /e
    cls
    echo Profile Backed up.
    Exit
)

If "%value%"=="6" (
    taskkill /im "firefox.exe"
    robocopy %source% %destination% /e
    start "" "C:\Program Files\FireFox\firefox.exe"
    echo FireFox restarted.
) ELSE (  # This always seems to execute even if I choose "yes" from the msgbox above.
    echo wscript.quit MsgBox("Will not close FF and not back up profile.", 0, "Keep open"^) > nocopy.vbs
    wscript //nologo nocopy.vbs
    del nocopy.vbs
)
```

If FireFox is closed, it runs the block where it copies the folder and then exits the script.

However, if it's open, I am not sure how to get the `%valueerror%` to be read.  If FireFox is open, I just want to ask the user if they want it to be closed or not.  If so, then kill the process, copy info, and restart it.  Otherwise, just show a simple message saying it won't close, and end the script.

Comment: Where is the variable `%value%` coming from? _because based upon what you've provided `""` will nver be equal to `"6"`!_ Using the correct/recommended method of defining your variables would help, change `set value = %ERRORLEVEL%` to `Set "value=%ERRORLEVEL%"` instead!

Comment: @Compo - Thanks! I changed it to `Set "value=%ERRORLEVEL%"` but it doesn't affect the outcome, still get the final `ELSE` block.  If I add `echo %value%` right after the `Set` line, it shows `0` regardless if I click "Yes" or "No". (Again, I'm very new to batch-files so might be overlooking some very obvious things...)

Comment: You also need to follow the recommendation from my initial comment when defining `%source%` and `%destination%`. Why are you using the `/N` option with `find.exe`?

Comment: @Compo - I updated `source` and `destination` to `set "source=C:\...."` but nothing changes, still get the final `ELSE`.  If you are referring to the `tasklist` line, it's because ...that's the code I found online and it seems to work. Not sure why the newline is in there.

Comment: @Compo - I've even tried just doing `IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="6"` (with and without the `%`) and it still always skips that block and goes to the `ELSE`...It's just `0` when I do `echo "%ERRORLEVEL%"` right before the `IF "%value%" ...` line. Edit: I think I'm getting to the bottom of it. After the `wscript //nologo yesno.vbs` line, I do `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` and it's always `0` no matter what I choose...so it's not being updated to reflect my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "source=C:\users\someUser\someFolder\FireFox\Profiles\wszashe.default"
set "destination=C:\users\someUser\someOtherFolder\"

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" 2>nul | find /I "firefox.exe" >nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
    > yesno.vbs echo wscript.quit MsgBox("Want to close FireFox?", 4, "Please choose."^)
    wscript //nologo yesno.vbs
    set "value=!ERRORLEVEL!"
    del yesno.vbs

    if !value! equ 6 (
        taskkill /F /FI "firefox.exe"
        robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /e
        start "" "%ProgramFiles%\FireFox\firefox.exe"
        echo FireFox restarted.
    ) else (
        > nocopy.vbs echo wscript.quit MsgBox("Will not close FF and not back up profile.", 0, "Keep open"^)
        wscript //nologo nocopy.vbs
        del nocopy.vbs
    )
) else (
    robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /e
    cls
    echo Profile Backed up.
    exit /b 0
)
```

Fixes:

- Setting values to variable names:

  ```
  set source = "..."
  ```

  is `%source %` and `"..."` with a leading space, as the literal names and values can include spaces as a part of them.

  So use:

  ```
  set "source=..."
  ```

  and add the quotes later when you use the variable. No spaces exist around the name or the value now.
- Check integers without quotes and use `equ`. The strings may work in your usage of `==`, though working with integers can change if you use `lss` etc. So change:

  ```
  if "!value!" == "6" (
  ```

  to

  ```
  if !value! equ 6 (
  ```
- I mentioned about using quotes later, change:

  ```
  robocopy %source% %destination% /e
  ```

  to

  ```
  robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /e
  ```
- To avoid echoing trailing spaces with example:

  ```
  echo ... > yesno.vbs
  ```

  put the redirection before the command:

  ```
  > yesno.vbs echo ...
  ```

To close `cmd.exe`, use `exit`. To close a `batch-file`, use `exit /b`. View `exit /?` for help.

I removed the `/N` argument from `find` as it is obsolete as you just want to find `firefox.exe` and check `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I found the right solution. I think it was the way that the script handles variables when compiling.  By tweaking the `IF` blocks and adding `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` to the top, it seems to be working now:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set source = "C:\users\someUser\someFolder\FireFox\Profiles\wszashe.default"
set destination = "C:\users\someUser\someOtherFolder\"
@echo off

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "firefox.exe">NUL
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    echo wscript.quit MsgBox("Want to close FireFox?", 4, "Please choose."^) > yesno.vbs
    wscript //nologo yesno.vbs
    set value = !ERRORLEVEL!
    del yesno.vbs

    If "!value!"=="6" (
        taskkill /F /FI "firefox.exe"
        robocopy %source% %destination% /e
        start "" "C:\Program Files\FireFox\firefox.exe"
        echo FireFox restarted.
    ) ELSE (
        echo wscript.quit MsgBox("Will not close FF and not back up profile.", 0, "Keep open"^) > nocopy.vbs
        wscript //nologo nocopy.vbs
        del nocopy.vbs
    )
) ELSE (
    robocopy %source% %destination% /e
    cls
    echo Profile Backed up.
    Exit
)
```

Comment: that won't work. You are defining variables, you never use (`%source %`, `%destination %`, `%value %`) and use variables, you never defined (`%source%`, `%destination%`, `%value%`)